# xbuild - where is the compiled app?

Tags: mono, xbuild

I have just started using xbuild to compile my C# solutions using Visual Stuido's .sln files. The outcome is two folders: bin and obj placed in the same localization as the .cs files of the project.

Both of them contain folders for Debug and Release versions, and both those versions appear to be the same application when I run them.

Is there any difference between those apps in bin and obj? And if there is, which one is the "complete app" I am "supposed to" run? Or am I missing some flag/option? Which files are necessary for the app to run (if I wanted to move just the executables and would like run them, which ones are necessary?)

I am using OSX (10.10.2), XBuild 12.0 and Mono 3.10.0.0 , if that is necessary.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short:

bin/Release/ are the files you should deploy.

bin/Debug/ are the files you should test in your developer machines.

Files in obj/ are useless, you can remove them.